# Sorting a list using Lambda

Tags: c++, list, sorting, c++11, shared-ptr

I need to sort a member-list of shared_ptr. But my code always throws errors when using lambda-expressions (probably since I am not used to lambda).

```
void myClass::orderList() {
   myList.sort([](shared_ptr<otherClass> v1, shared_ptr<otherClass> v2){ return (v1->id > v2->id);});
}
```

with "myClass" having the member-variable

```
list<shared_ptr<otherClass>> myList;
```

What do I have to write into the brackets[]. I do not get behind it. Thanks

**EDIT**

So this is my "real" code

```
vertices.sort([](const shared_ptr<Vertex>& v1, const shared_ptr<Vertex>& v2){return v1->getDijkstraDist() < v2->getDijkstraDist();});
```

and the error reads

```
Queue.cpp: In member function ‘void Queue::orderList()’:
Queue.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
Queue.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
Queue.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
Queue.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
```

As you can guess, vertices is the member-variable of Queue. And Vertex got a constructor taking 3 arguments.

Comment: 1) what error do you get? (I can't reproduce the problem with the code shown, but I also dont know what otherClass is) 2) use `const shared_ptr<otherClass>&` to avoid unneeded copies 3) braces in `return (a > b)` are unneeded and harder to read than `return a > b` 4) you don't need anything in [], there's nothing to capture

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error? Have you tried to use const reference instead of passing by value?

Comment: Could it be that you are compiling without c++11 support (-std=c++11 for gcc)?

Comment: Oh, I am forced to use an old compiler. Thus, I got -std=c++0x (since -std=c++11 throws compiler errors). But actually, smart pointers work using this compile flag. I found another solution using std::bind but I think lambda expressions are cooler :) So do you think the c++0x and c++11 makes the difference?

Comment: Not that familiar with gcc but older versions might not have lambdas with the c++0x. Just test it yourself: create a source file with minimal code and a lambda, compile with c++0x and the c++11 flags and see what happens. Also in the end the proper solution here is most likely to get c++11 support and all the good stuff it has and fix the compiler errors you have: sticking to old standards only makes upgrading harder in the future

Comment: Okay, but thanks a lot. At least I can be sure that I somehow understood lambdas correctly :)

Comment: If you have no lambdas, you will need to create a comparer object and define the operator<(const shared_ptr<Vertex>& v1, const shared_ptr<Vertex>& v2)

Comment: I came to this solution which fits my needs:   vertices.sort(std::bind(&Queue::compare, this, _1, _2));    where bool compare(..) is my compare-fct. Nevertheless, lambda would be nicer ;)